# Вопросы в духе "Почему разработчики языка/библиотеки сделали так?"

Tags: обсуждение

Собственно данный вопрос родился из [комментариев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/554480/106) к вопросу ["Почему для static-метода нельзя опустить имя класса?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554472/106). Разрешать или нет?

Comment: Похоже, можно принимать ответ.

Comment: И подправить правила было бы неплохо.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Разрешать**

Такие вопросы либо не имеют ответа (информации просто нет в публичном доступе), либо имеют четкий, однозначный и приемлемый по объему ответ. Подобные ответы безусловно способствуют ликбезу и соотносятся с духом "энциклопедии знаний".

Comment: У Эрика Липперта в блоге много постов, объясняющих мотивацию того или иного решения разработчиков языка.

Comment: @VladD, с другой стороны, не у всех разработчиков есть такие блоги как у Эрика Липперта :)

Comment: @Grundy: Да, но что ж, из-за этого запрещать задавать интересные вопросы?

Comment: @VladD, но ведь вопросы, на которые _нельзя_ дать ответ - оффтопик? и в данном _конкретном_ случае вопрос будет оффтопиком, конечно, если вдруг не объявится автор языка :-)

Comment: @Grundy: А откуда мы априори знаем, что на вопрос _нельзя_ дать ответ?

Comment: @VladD, это да :-) какая-то неразрешимая задача

Comment: @Grundy нельзя дать ответ -- это из другой оперы. Все подобные вопросы ответ имеют. Другое дело, что не все доступны публике. Что ж, значит некоторые вопросы останутся без ответов.

Comment: Как правило, это отличные вопросы, а ответы на них раскрывают глубинное устройство языка и аппелируют к фундаментальным принципам программирования. Лучше один такой вопрос в день, чем 150 про жиквери-плюгины!

Answer (score -5):

**Запретить**

Из правил:

> Не задавайте вопросы со множеством возможных ответов или требующие
>   одного, но очень длинного ответа