# Следует ли закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, причины-закрытия

Для меня ответ очевиден, но оказалось, что есть люди с 10K+ репутацией, которые не согласны с [цитатой](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason#comment106655_274630) @Shog9♦︎:

> *clearly-written "how do I do X using Y?" questions are pretty useful, even if they don't contain code.*

Какое мнение сообщества на эту тему? Какие аргументы за/против можно использовать?

Comment: И кто же им накидал столько репы?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Вообще-то все как раз наоборот.

Закрывать надо вопросы вида "вот вам код, разберитесь, почему он не работает".

Подавляющее большинство людей, заходящих на Stack Overflow, совершенно неверно представляют себе миссию и методы работы этого сайта, принимая его за привычный форум, где одни энтузиасты с жаром копаются в коде других энтузиастов, но при этом минусуют вопросы без кода, оставляя комментарии вида "а сам ты что сделал?".

В то время как единственным критерием удачности вопроса является его **полезность для других программистов.** И если ответ помог только автору исправить 100500-ю опечатку в его коде, то это был плохой, негодный вопрос.

А если ответ дает каноническое решение какой-либо базовой задачи, то значит вопрос был очень хороший, несмотря на то, что автор - "бездельник" и "тунеядец", не осиливший написать и две строчки кода.

Comment: Золотые слова. Кратко и ясно.

Comment: в тему: [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Answer (score 39):

## Нет, отсутствие кода - не повод закрывать вопрос.

Или, если следовать строгой матлогике:

- **Неверно, что следует закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода**
- **Существуют вопросы, в которых нет кода и которые не следует закрывать**

Не следует ориентироваться только на наличие или отсутствие кода. Код — всего лишь формальный признак. Для многих хороших вопросов код не нужен даже в ответе (может быть достаточно диаграмм или псевдокода).

Гораздо важнее возможность дать на поставленный вопрос однозначный достоверный ответ, который умещается максимум в страницу-две и будет полезен широкому кругу читателей.

Более того, если вопрос без кода предполагает в ответе какие-то фундаментальные знания, алгоритмы, архитектуру, концепции — этот вопрос гораздо ценнее множества практических решений на тему "как мне сложить именно эти два числа, используя jQuery". Хороший пример таких вопросов: [Вопросы в духе "Почему разработчики языка/библиотеки сделали так?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3522/181472)

**Исключение**: код *непосредственно в вопросе* нужен для вопросов "где ошибка в моём коде?", "почему у меня не работает программа", и тому подобных. Когда вместо кода дана ссылка на онлайн-IDE, gist, облачное хранилище или сайт, на котором не работает код (это хуже всего) - вопрос стоит закрыть в чисто дисциплинарных целях. Мы не должны бегать за кодом куда-то, откуда он завтра может исчезнуть.

---

Другое дело, когда "how do I do X using Y?" превращается в ["Как мне написать мою лабораторную используя `%language%`, но не вникая в него? Дайте готовый код!"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0). Это отдельная проблема, слабо связанная с наличием в вопросе кода.

Comment: Почему меня как будущего читателя вопроса, интересующегося "как сделать X, используя %language%", должно волновать что у исходного автора вопроса это была лабораторная? Назначение Stack Overflow ответить на вопрос так, чтобы ответы были полезны и другим людям с тем же вопросом, а не только для автора вопроса. Хотя это уже [тема "работа за автора" (гораздо более сложная)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044), а не тема "вопрос без кода" (я ожидал, что это всем очевидно, что такие вопросы могут быть полезны. То есть нельзя судить вопрос только по тому есть в нём код или нет).

Comment: Не могли бы вы для ясности сверху ответа вашу позицию однозначно обозначить, например, добавить фразу "Не следует" с жирным форматированием (содержимое ответа уже эту точку зрения содержит, но я хочу чтобы это было ясно даже тем кто два слова только из ответа прочтёт).

Comment: @jfs дополнил, жду обратной связи

Comment: ответ не достаточно категоричен (то есть я согласен с тем что сказано, но ваш ответ пытается на какой-то другой вопрос ответить) Я спросил:  *"Следует ли закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода?"*  (предельно простой вопрос, с непротиворечивым ответом для подавляющего большинства людей), а вы зачем-то полезли в гораздо более сложную, неочевидную, с богатой историей тему "работа за автора". Приходится иметь дело с людьми, которые не хотят и не будут ничего читать/вникать/понимать. Поэтому на вопрос: *"Следует ли закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода?"* ожидаемый ответ: "нет, не следует".

Comment: @jfs Если быть предельно корректным, то "Неверно, что следует закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода" или "Существуют вопросы, в которых нет кода и которые не следует закрывать". Предлагаете прямо так написать?

Comment: согласен с обоими формулировками. Вопрос в том как их добавить, чтобы при самом невнимательном чтении ответа, они глаз бы зацепили.

Answer (score 16):

## **НЕТ**

Бывают случаи, когда привести код нельзя, к примеру, если обсуждаются общие черты алгоритма, или *"как получить A если известен B"*, *"какой алгоритм оптимальный"* и т.д. 
Нельзя считать наличие кода показателем качества вопроса, ведь вопросы бывают разные.
Но можно сделать метку "нет кода" или что-то вроде того, для тех, кому не нравятся/нравятся  вопросы/ответы без кода.

Answer (score 2):

Нет конечно однозначный ответ. Существует условно два типа вопросов, теоретические и практические. Теоретические могут быть вообще без кода, то есть, человек даже не может понять, как дойти до начало практической реализации. Например, как написать тетрис? ведь нужно примерно представлять алгоритмы, которые нужно использовать при написании. Зато зная их, можно брать любой язык, хоть js,c++,python и писать код, и вот в процессе написания на каждом языке, будет возникать тот самый второй тип вопросов, который я условно назвал практический, потому что они уже будут относиться к конкретному языку, и иметь в вопросе код. И таких вопросов много, особенно у людей начинающих в чем то разбираться, и у которых отсутствуют именно теоретические знания.