# Переводы тривиальных вопросов с ангийского so

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-содержимого

Снова задумался над темой [популяризации сайта ru-so](/questions/4072/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0) и снова захотел немного попереводить вопросы по тегу ansible с "большого" so.

Столкнулся вот с какой проблемой. Да, на [русском вопросов по ansible](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) мало, а на английском на первый взгляд [много](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible).

Однако, когда начинаешь выбирать вопросы для перевода -- на деле оказывается, что 95% вопросов -- это вопросы настолько тривиальные, что возникает вопрос "а стоит ли это вообще усилий по переводу?" Конкретные примеры -- [Как создать папку при помощи ansible?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/22844905/how-to-create-a-directory-using-ansible) или [Как переименовать файл на удалённом хосте используя Ansible?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/24162996/how-to-move-rename-a-file-using-an-ansible-task-on-a-remote-system). Стоит начать перерывать популярные (читай: заплюсованные) вопросы -- окажется, что таких "новичковых" вопросов будет подавляющее большинство.

С одной стороны, любая масса вопросов на русском -- это дополнительный трафик из поисковиков -- поэтому перевод наверное всё же потенциально востребован. С другой стороны -- настолько низкий уровень вопросов это не очень хорошо в плане качества аудитории, которая привлекается.

По теме переводов с английского so был давний [вопрос на мете](/questions/70/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-so), но там такой аспект не подымался.

Comment: Составляйте собственный топ вопросов и переводите по нему. Можно выбирать по балансу интересности и популярности. Можно посмотреть, что люди гуглят и давать ответы на эти вопросы.

Comment: Ну и вы не обязаны переводить слово-в-слово и переносить *недостатки* исходных ответов. Вы можете собирать лучшее из разных ответов и в результате получать прямо-таки шедевр. )

Answer (score 12):

Как я [писал здесь недавно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3892/179379), любой вопрос, который формулирует четкую проблему, имеет право на существование. И даже более того - приветствуется. Я не знаю деталей для конкретного тега, но сам по себе вопрос "Как создать папку при помощи ansible?" звучит просто как хрестоматийный топик для SO.

Относительный же "уровень" вопроса не играет здесь ни малейшей роли. Или, опять же, даже наоборот - СО задумывался своими создателями как противоположность снобизму подписчиков мейллистов, фыркающих в ответ на детские вопросы.

Comment: Если добавить "как **правильно** создать папку при помощи ansible" вопрос становится не таким уж и тривиальным. Например, `mode: 644` неправильно, `mode: 0644` правильно. А ещё почти всегда важно, какому пользователю она должна принадлежать, но об этом легко забыть. В общем, это отличный вопрос. )

Answer (score 6):

Вставлю свои 5 копеек. Я недавно зарегистрировался на SO (а до этого был просто анонимусом), но крайне много базовых знаний подчерпнул именно на SO. Поэтому мои аргументы:

1. От того, что вы отвечаете на простой вопрос, вы не поощряете людей находится на низком уровне. Напротив, вы ликвидируете безграмотность. Поэтому чем больше будет простых, но фундаментальных вопросов будет задано и отвечено, тем, скорее всего, выше будет уровень людей.

   Особо важную роль здесь играет то, что отвечающий не относится к задающему вопрос свысока и несерьёзно, а напротив, старается ответить ему как можно доступней, и в то же время старался ему дать как можно более концентрированный и полный ответ.
2. Очень много вопросов на первый взгляд кажущихся простыми, таковыми не являются. И если ответ действительно глубокий, то он способен продемонстрировать нюансы и сведения, которые не все профессионалы знают. Или даже просто посмотреть с другой стороны на казалось бы уже банальные вещи. К примеру вопрос про [CSS треугольник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work).
3. Вопросы могут просто систематизировать ваши знания. Вот вопрос на C# [Для чего нужны свойства?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197067/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0). Я не могу сказать, что тут узнал что-то новое, но ответ очень классно систематизирует, те знание которые есть.
4. Хороший ответ на простой вопрос, может быть отличным мини-справочником. Вы, например, помните все случаи назубок [от чего в JavaScript избавляет "use strict"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435546/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-use-strict)? Я нет.
5. Очень часто даже профессионалы имеют пробелы или какую-то дезинформацию в чём-то фундаментальном. Или просто недопонимают или просто не знают какой-то нюанс, связанный с азами. Если пренебрегать азами, то устранять подобные бреши придётся другому ресурсу.

---

Я когда-то считал несправедливым что у простых вопросов намного больше репутации. Но по изложенным выше причинам поменял своё мнение. Также советую прочитать ответы на [схожий вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/616/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Поэтому призываю не относится к новичкам свысока, а старательно и скрупулёзно отвечать на их вопросы, особенно если таковые не задавались раннее. Чем интересней и старательней будет ответ, тем больше вы людей вдохновите достигать (а возможно и превосходить) ваш уровень.