# Что делать если вопросы закрываются по "благим" намерениям, но по липовым причинам?

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия

Иногда вопросы закрываются по неподходящим причинам из-за отсутствия явных причин в интерфейсе сайта, отражающих точку зрения закрывающего.

К примеру, на сайте нет официальных причин:

- закрыть потому что можно [ответить с помощью поиска в Гугле](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/23044)
- закрыть потому что [вопрос не содержит кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3851/23044)
- закрыть как ["домашнее задание"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

и люди пытаются подогнать вопрос под уже существующие причины такие как: "Не по теме", "слишком общий".

Чтобы всем по приведённым ссылкам не ходить, кратко: основная идея исходит из того факта, что полезные вопросы существуют, чтобы их *задали один раз, а их ответы просматривали бы много людей<sup>*</sup>*, никак с автором вопроса несвязанных, кроме того, что они имеют похожую проблему -- одна и та же проблема может возникнуть у многих людей. См. [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Другие сайты могут иметь другие приоритеты, но Stack Overflow это не школа, и мы не на экзамене, где запрещено списывать. Stack Overflow это сайт вопросов и ответов. Акцент именно на содержимом, а не авторах вопросов/ответов и их воображаемом моральном облике.

Тема типа "Работа за автора" -- непростая, противоречивая и не такая очевидная как может показаться на первый взгляд. Если у вас есть что сказать именно об этой теме, [опубликуйте свой ответ в соответствующем обсуждении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044).

Многие вопросы, который закрываются по надуманным причинам, являются плохими вопросами.

Вопрос в том, почему вместо того, чтобы предлагать новые причины закрытия, чтобы эти плохие вопросы закрыть, или подумать, что есть хорошие основания для отсутствия некоторых причин закрытия на сайте, некоторые участники *злоупотребляют уже существующими причинами закрытий*. И как можно было бы минимизировать вред от подобного поведения, чтобы небольшая доля пользователей не диктовала бы свою политику, в разрез с результатами обсуждений на Мете.

Вот [пример, который вдохновил это обсуждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633622/23044): в последней реинкарнации вопрос был закрыт как "слишком общий", но при этом он имеет достаточно деталей, для ответа (причём как в варианте [как я его увидел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/633622/2), так и [в текущем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/633622/4)). Поэтому мой ответ (который я  опубликовал не заметив, что автор вопрос изменил), отвечает на оба варианта. Более того, если вы Питон знаете, то по *уже приведённым ответам* можно посмотреть, что достаточно всего нескольких строк кода, чтобы решить задачу. Для людей, незнакомых с Питоном, упомяну, что я мог бы остановится на одном примере кода. То что мой ответ содержит несколько решений -- это просто исследование вариаций на тему с моей стороны. **Наличие [детального](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/628946/23044) [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431760/23044) не делает вопрос слишком общим** [просто иногда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/527815/23044) [такие ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044) [получаются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621251/23044) (по ссылкам примеры моих ответов как  доказательство что это не уникальный случай).

Пожалуйста, не используйте причину "вопрос слишком общий", если уже существуют адекватные ответы на вопрос, чтобы вы не думали о лени/компетенции автора вопроса.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>[Site analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources) говорит, что 95% трафика из поисковиков. То есть 19 из 20 человек вероятно будут рады решение для своей проблемы увидеть, вместо сообщения что вопрос закрыт так как автор тупой лентяй по мнению некоторых участников. Ещё пример: [`94.4%` загрузок страниц (от не ботов) приходится на страницы с самими вопросами (для сравнения: только `1.31%` приходится на домашнюю страницу SO).](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/)</sub>

Comment: Очевидно что - открывать вопрос, а закрывающим чёрный бобик модеров приедет.

Comment: @Other: учитывая, что вы один из закрывающих [вопроса из примера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633622/23044), не могли вы добавить ответ здесь и описать процесс: как вы пришли к решению закрыть этот вопрос.

Comment: Просто посчитал что нужно закрыть.

Comment: @Other: я вас и прошу объяснить почему вы решили закрыть (в виде ответа, для подробностей). Или вы хотите сказать, что никто вам никто не указ -- голосую как хочу -- вне зависимости от правил, принятых сообществом?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Is "too broad" a valid reason to close a question that doesn't show any research effort?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283177/4279)

Answer (score 12):

Я согласен. Есть довольно много вопросов, которые имели проблемы с качеством, но были закрыты не по правильной причине. Это, скорее всего, из за лени самих проверяющих пользователей, которые ленятся перейти в пункт "Не по теме, потому что..." и написать собственную причину закрытия вопроса.

Дорогие пользователи-проверяющие, хочу обратить внимание, что неправильно поставленная причина может влечь за собой последствия. К примеру, автор может неправильно исправить свой вопрос. Эта правка сделает его ещё хуже и непонятнее. Вследствие модераторы обратят внимание на очень некачественный вопрос и просто напросто полностью удалят его.

Так что не ленитесь, указывайте настоящие причины закрытия, чтобы улучшить качество вопроса, а не для того, чтобы поставить галочку.

Так же, я бы посоветовал, не спешить голосовать за закрытие вопроса, если можно его исправить самим. Замечал, что многие закрытые вопросы можно было исправить самим. Но, к сожалению, у нас пользователи ленятся уделить пару минут вопросу и сразу нажимают на закрытие.

Пожалуйста, больше внимания обращайте на вопросы, если их можно улучшить, то делайте это максимально на сколько можно.

*И как же без итога:* И я уверен, что *ruSO* станет лучшим сайтом-справочником для начинающих программистов.

Comment: Только вот [у нас участники, а не пользователи](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1054/176217).

Comment: @alexolut, мне кажется, что это синонимы. Хотя пользователи, это люди которые пользуются *(люди задающие вопросы и те, которые берут решения с ответов)*, а участники - это люди, которые участвуют в жизни сайта *(отвечающие, голосующие, закрывающие и т.д.)* :) Тут спорно

Comment: @Yuri: учитывая что вы один из закрывающих вопроса в примере, мне хотелось бы вашу логику понять, почему вы решили закрыть вопрос в примере?  Если не как "слишком общий", то какую причину закрытия вы имели в виду? Как это по вашему согласуется с решениями сообщества в приведённых выше ссылках? Вы не знали о них или вам всё равно?

Comment: @jfs, какой именно вопрос? Киньте ссылку. Я не нашёл у вас :)

Comment: @Yuri http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633622/Каким-образом-удалить-строчки-выборочно

Comment: @jfs но правка от автора честно говоря поменяла всю суть вопроса, некрасиво так делать... А раз его изменили так радикально, то может он действительно был непонятен?

Comment: @pavel, я не знаю и не помню, почему я его закрыл. Сейчас он выглядит вполне корректно. Я очень сильно извиняюсь.

Comment: @jfs, благодарю, что обратили моё внимание. Надеюсь такого больше не повторю

Comment: @Yuri: к вашему ответу: дело не в лени (или по-меньшей мере не только и не столько в ней). Когда я комментирую под подобными вопросами (и говорю, что не нужно вопрос закрывать, не смотря на то что решение в гугле можно найти, не смотря на то что вопрос код не содержит, не смотря на то, что кажется что вопрос из категории "Работа за автора" -- посмотрите ссылки на самом верху), некоторые люди (ожидаемо, так как эти мета-вопросы далеко не очевидны) ведут себя по принципу: автор-тунеядец -> вопрос закрыть (вне зависимости от пользы самого вопроса).

Comment: @pavel: оба варианты понятны (убрать строки в файле через одну, убрать по другому условию). Почему автор изменил так резко? -- не знаю, может его напугали закрытием вопроса ([требует *правки*] статус) и он попытался сделать *правку*: сделать вопрос более общим -- но это только догадки с моей стороны. Верно, что менять смысл вопроса, если это делает неверными существующие ответы не стоит, но мой ответ ещё не был опубликован на тот момент (несколько секунд позже я опубликовал ответ, не увидев, что вопрос поменялся).

Comment: @jfs, я бы хотел обсудить с вами написания причины закрытия некоторых вопросов в [своём чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52027/communication-with-the-yuri). Чтобы указывать конкретные причины закрытия.

Comment: @Yuri: если вы хотите предложить новую причину закрытия, то создайте отдельное мета-обсуждение.

Answer (score 2):

Так как никто так и не назвал причины закрытия обсуждаемого вопроса, то я назову свою, если я ее правильно помню. Приведу здесь также и исходный текст вопроса в том виде, в каком я его увидел. Вкратце, да, причина - "Работа за автора":

**Требуется удалить строчки через одну**

> Нужен код python для удаления строчек в файле через одну, начиная со
>   второй. Как это лучше сделать?

Для меня подобный текст - это явный *триггер* - создается ощущение, что автор просит, но просит без уважения. Вот именно так - текст составлен не "Как сделать то-то, мой код приводит к таким-то и таким-то ошибкам", а "Метнись, потрать час и накидай мне код да такой, чтобы все летало". Это ощущение создают фразы, слова триггеры - "Требуется", "Нужен код", отсутствие примера входа-выхода. Короче, отсутствие минимального примера. Очевидно (очевидно ли?), если бы автор мог составить минимальный пример, то и вопроса бы не возникло в таком виде.

Я намеренно нагнал эмоциональной окраски, но судя по тому, что было аж 10 разных закрывающих - она в той или иной степени верна. Закрывающий видит *триггер* и после этого любые рассуждения о качестве не работают - работает только крик "Жги ведьму!". Особенно, если это кричишь не ты один, а толпа. А толпа завелась и вопрос закрыли с молниеносной скоростью. Часто закрывашки висят днями и неделями, но не в этот раз.

Я попытался загнать свою обиду подальше, написал комментарий и только после этого клацнул на закрывашку, однако, я не дождался реакции автора и не дал ему шанса поправить вопрос или ответить на комментарий. Часто реакции никакой не следует, но это другой вопрос.

В данном случае на самом деле невозможно сказать, действительно автор "бездельник" или у него это слог такой и он пальцы себе стер гуглить и обратился к SO как к самому крайнему средству в полном отчаянии. Возникает вопрос: как подавить в себе Инквизитора? Как не жечь ведьм? Уже было много раз написано, что если это домашнее задание, то пройди мимо или закрой по четким формальным признакам. Но данное правило не совсем работает и совсем НЕ работает на подобных вопросах - я точно знаю, что это далеко не единственный пример, за который я голосовал. И у них у всех одинаковые триггеры и одинаково молниеносная реакция сообщества. Это однократное обсуждение вряд ли изменит ситуацию - парочка закрывающих будет осторожней, но их довольно много и парочка голосов роли не играет.

Что может каждый сделать, чтобы избежать закрытия таких вопросов? Отредактировать его, удалив триггеры (как это сделал NicolasChabanovsky)? Вопрос без триггеров для меня смотрится по-другому и я бы скорее пропустил его, дождался реакции автора, чем взялся бы за вилы и своевременная редактура может помочь избежать охоты. Добавить примеров?

Comment: Весьма признателен, что вы высказали своё искреннее мнение (хотя и не разделяю его). Не могли вы явно упомянуть как вы относитесь к идее, высказанной в вопросе: *«важно только содержимое вопросов/ответов, вне зависимости от морального облика автора* — большинство посещений вопросов из гугла (посмотрите на статистику в конце вопроса), поэтому следует думать о будущих посетителях,  а не что из себя автор вопроса (по-видимому) представляет». Как вы думаете помогает ли большинству людей закрытие вопросов, описывающих проблему, которая у многих людей может возникнуть? ...

Comment: ...[продолжение] Что по вашему думают посетители из гугла приземлившись на закрытый вопрос? Способствует ли это миссии сайта? [*"We all have these little tiny pieces of information and if we can just contribute a little bit, that information gets amplified, and maybe a thousand other dumb developers will benefit from my one little piece of good information."*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us/)

Comment: @jfs, все ваши замечания верны и идею я разделяю (однако, ее надо было явно высказать в таком виде, чтобы до меня дошло)-не нужно играть в экзаменаторов, профессоров и полицию нравов, мы пришли отвечать на вопросы, а не рядить людей (даже не совсем людей - картинку на экране) в "бездельник" или "небездельник". Более того, доподлинно неизвестно, действительно это так или только кажется.Человеку с таким же вопросом, пришедшему из гугла абсолютно без разницы-он хочет получить ответ на вопрос, а не жечь ведьм.Закрытие не помогает и пришедшему захочется задать такой же вопрос или разочаровнно уйти.

Comment: ваш комментарий звучит как пересказ точки зрения, выраженной в вопросе (что не следует полезные вопросы закрывать вне зависимости от автора). Но вы проголосовали за закрытие. Вы изменили свою точку зрения?

Comment: @jfs, да, относительно обсуждаемого вопроса изменил - теперь я думаю, что надо было его отредактировать, чтобы оно звучало более нейтрально. Полно вопросов "Как сделать то-то", но на закрытие нарываются только те, в которых автор выражает свою просьбу словами "Требуется" и т.д. Для меня именно это являлось причиной (вот такой вот я чувствительный), а не отсутсвие кода или еще чего-то. Вот еще подобный пример, также закрытый мной - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/142970 Даже в нем я бы теперь подумал, стоит ли его закрыть или подредактировать, а не сразу же нажал на кнопку.