# Удаление собственного заминусованного и закрытого вопроса при наличии ответов

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, удаление-вопросов, голоса-против

Здравствуйте!

Вот мой вопрос: «[JavaSript вывод цепочки сообщений в console](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/617230/234502)».

Я попытался его удалить еще примерно месяц назад, но получил ошибку:

> Приносим свои извинения, но на этот вопрос уже получены ответы и удалить его нельзя, но вы можете отметить его тревогой, чтобы обратить внимание модератора на него.

Я отметил тревогой и описал, почему хочу его удалить. Тревога провисела продолжительное время со статусом `в ожидании`. Сегодня я увидел статус `полезные`, но при этом сообщение не было удалено.

Если за вопрос я получил немало минусов и его закрыли, это означает, что для сообщества он считается бесполезным и его стоит удалить, тем более если автор вопроса (то есть я) сам хочет это сделать.

Но удалить его у меня не получается, и пометка его тревогой также ничего не решила.

Предлагаю все же удалить его, а если нет (он представляет какую-то пользу) — то открыть его и убрать минусы.

**UPDATE 27.03.17**
Поскольку ответа от модератор/администратора я не получил, следовательно подведу итоги данной темы в одностороннем порядке:

**1).** На SOru мета мне можно более подробные вопросы не задавать, метка `Поддержка` ничего здесь не значит. Можно договориться, но для этого нужно говорить(обсуждать), худший вариант, когда нет ответа.

**2).** Убедился, что на данном ресурсе существует некоторый произвол со стороны людей получивших небольшую "власть". Эти слова для меня означают следующее, когда поступки человека совершаются по его собственному усмотрению, без всякого обязательства давать за них ответ в будущем или хоть как-то комментировать их.
*В этом для меня есть и положительная сторона, т.к. вспоминая данный произвол, в будущем буду стараться следить за собой и не допускать подобного поведения.

**3).** Заданный здесь вопрос оказывается может быть плохим и заслуживать осуждения в виде его закрытия и активного минусования, но одновременно он может быть и хорошим, т.к. потенциально может принести кому-то пользу, а следовательно он является ценным и удалять его нельзя. В моем понимании может быть только одно из этих двух, но в понимании другого человека эти два состояния могут быть одновременно.
*Если кому-то кажется ценным ответ, а не вопрос, но тогда и вопрос сразу становится ценным, т.к. логично, что если бы не было вопроса, то и не было бы ответа.

**Надеюсь, данное мое заключение не вызовет у кого-нибудь гнев, я постарался написать максимально корректно, и конечно, каждый человек имеет право на свое мнение.

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: А не пробовали  отозвать принятие вопроса (галку) и минуснуть ответ?

Comment: а зачем удалять вообще, если можно было просто отредактировать?

Comment: Благодарю за ваши комментарии! **avp** Я попробовал снять принятие ответа, это не помогло, удалить система не дает. **Grundy**  Данный вопрос слишком общий и в нем непонятна суть вопроса, я это признаю(когда я задавал данный вопрос я почти совсем не знал js и это было мое первое сообщение на данном ресурсе). Сейчас не понятно, что там менять, т.к. ответ уже не интересует, разве что, я могу его переделать в code review, когда сам код напишу под данную задачу и выложу.

Comment: Меня удивляет молчание модераторов, ведь должен быть какой-то ответ... иначе зачем данный раздел существует. Повторю что меня интересует, если вопрос минусуют и закрывают, то это означает что он бесполезен для сообщества, и конечно его можно легко удалить, тем более когда сам автор это пытается сделать. Если это не так, то я хочу знать, почему он до сих пор не удален, и что значат на данном ресурсе минусы и закрытие вопроса.

Comment: Часто [некоторые в частники закрывают вопрос по липовой причине](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4868/23044), если автор не продемонстрировал достаточно по их мнению усилий вместо/в дополнение к минусу за вопрос. Отсутствие официальной причины закрытия ["работа за автора"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044) не случайно¶ Если принятый  ответ  решает проблему в вопросе, как вы её понимали в тот момент, то не хорошо пытаться удалить такой ответ. Возможно стоит отредактировать вопрос, чтобы прояснить его и чтобы люди с похожей проблемой могли бы легче приведённый ответ найти.

Comment: **jfs** благодарю вас за проявленный интерес к моей проблеме! Я описал выше в своем комментарии как задавался этот вопрос, могу лишь добавить, что ответивший на него, выполнил полностью за меня работу(мой код конечно был некорректным), конкретных вопросов у меня не было, кроме тех что по пунктам в задаче указаны, а они как раз и подразумевали выполнение работы полностью за меня. Если сейчас редактировать/добавлять вопрос, то может сложиться впечатление что был ответ именно на него, как помощь, хотя ответивший полностью решил задачу за меня. Задним числом я редактировать не хочу.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov читали ли вы ссылки, которые я выше привёл? Речь не о вас, а может ли ваш вопрос пригодится другим людям (могут ли другие люди иметь похожую проблему и  могут ли они найти ваш вопрос? Поможет ли им данный ответ? — если ответ **да**, хотя бы на один из этих вопросов, то не следует вопрос удалять. См. [Какими должны быть критерии оценки качества базы знаний?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)

Comment: **jfs** Темы на которые вы дали ссылки я сразу посмотрел. Вы задаете вопросы, но они не ко мне, т.к. я по своей воле не могу удалить вопрос, следовательно, удалить или нет, уже решил кто-то другой в одностороннем порядке. После своего вопроса в данной теме я рассчитывал от этого человека(модератора) получить ответ, чтобы понять логику подобных действий.  Видимо так обстоит дело  - вопрос плох и подходит для того чтобы его минуснуть и закрыть, но одновременно он также хорош, т.к. он может принести кому-то пользу и поэтому удалять его нельзя. В моем понимании, может быть только одно из этих двух

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, чтобы участнику, к которому ты обращаешься пришла нотификация о твоем ответе, ставь в сообщении `@` перед ником `@AlexandrKazakov`, а не выделяй полужирным. Иначе твой комментарий могут просто не увидеть

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov "могу/не могу удалить"  никак не связано с "могу оценить полезен/не полезен ответ".  Если вы читали ссылки, то должны понимать, что минусы и голоса за закрытие ставят обычные участники такие же как и вы. Разные участники могут по разному цели и задачи сайта воспринимать. Из того что вопрос плох и достоин минуса, ещё не значит, что его следует удалять (большинство вопросов плохие, вопрос только в какой степени). Вот посмотрите [вопрос, который был закрыт дважды и мой ответ на него](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633622/23044). По вашему, ответ следует удалить?

Comment: @jfs В вашем примере вопрос открыт в данный момент. В моем случае вопрос закрыт, пусть минусы там остаются, но пусть его тогда откроют, ведь это логично, ответ невозможно улучшить, т.к. на закрытый вопрос невозможно ответить другому. Если вопрос полезен, пусть станет еще лучше(за счет возможных новых ответов) - но нужно открыть его, если бесполезен, нужно удалить. Я кажется повторяюсь, логика очевидна(для меня). Править вопрос я не буду, т.к. ответивший отвечал на тот вопрос, как он сейчас записан, мне сейчас что-то менять - это заниматься сочинительством(придумать вымышленную историю и код).

Comment: Очень жаль, что мы люди, не можем договориться из-за такого пустяка. В данном вопросе стоит выступить модератору и все разъяснить, но возможно этого не случится, поскольку, что здесь можно сказать? так возможно: "Вопрос не будет открыт, т.к. он задан не по правилам/в нарушении правил, но он не будет и удален, т.к. представляет ценность и может быть полезен другим людям. Это звучит удивительно и нелогично, с момента создания данной темы я пытаюсь это донести. Сложно будет здесь четко ответить, разве что можно попытаться дать общую формулировку и несколько ссылок, на правила/обсуждение.

Comment: @jfs Я благодарен вам за то, что пытаетесь помочь и разъяснить, я посмотрел некоторые ваши ответы и комментарии, видимо вы немало сделали для данного ресурса. Я смотрел ссылки,что вы здесь привели, но там больше похоже на обсуждение, без конкретного заключения, и, понимая, что здесь люди порой поступают по своему усмотрению(анонимные минусы без каких-либо комментариев подтверждают это) не могу считать это за объяснение, т.к. большое кол-во людей может с этим не считаться. Стоит мне конечно уступить, пусть так вопрос остается.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173996/309650

Comment: В итоге сам задачу решил. Что интересно, после повторного открытия данного вопроса и перед тем как я открыл конкурс было пять минусов за вопрос, сегодня закрыл конкурс, стоит шесть минусов. Казалось бы, человек прислушался к мнению сообщества, отредактировал свой вопрос, но даже после этого нашлось немало людей кто минус поставил. Вот и получается, пиши "плохой" вопрос, мы тебе минус поставим, улучшай его/редактируй, мы тебе все равно минус поставим, а спросишь "за что", просто не скажем )

Answer (score 3):

> Приносим свои извинения, но на этот вопрос уже получены ответы и удалить его нельзя, но вы можете отметить его тревогой, чтобы обратить внимание модератора на него.

Да, вопросы с ответами самому удалять нельзя.

> Если за вопрос я получил немало минусов и его закрыли, это означает, что для сообщества он считается бесполезным и его стоит удалить, тем более если автор вопроса (то есть я) сам хочет это сделать.

Если сообщество захочет его удалить, оно и удалит. Я вижу кнопку удаления и при желании могу проголосовать за удаление. Предположу, что при наличии достаточной репутации ты бы тоже это мог. Но именно проголосовать, а не удалить единолично.

А ещё есть дух, который автоматически удаляет вопросы.

> Если кому-то кажется ценным ответ, а не вопрос, но тогда и вопрос сразу становится ценным, т.к. логично, что если бы не было вопроса, то и не было бы ответа.

Да, можно сказать, что вопрос становится ценным. Но это не означает, что любой такой вопрос стоит переоткрывать и ждать на него ещё хорошие ответы.

Я уже спрашивал, [зачем закрывать вопросы, на которые есть принятый ответ](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1244/178988). Решили, что эти события не связаны...

> Предлагаю все же удалить его, а если нет (он представляет какую-то пользу) — то открыть его и убрать минусы.

Основной вопрос - зачем?

- Удалить. Не увижу причин. Ну вопрос и вопрос. Не впечатляет, есть куча кода, в которой лень разбираться. Но кто-то разобрался и ответил. Почему его труд должен пропасть? Тем более, у него спишется рейтинг за этот ответ.
- Переоткрыть. Ответ уже дан, он тебя устраивает. Нужны ещё ответы? Вроде нет. Кто-то хочет ответить другим способом? Вряд ли. Мне кажется, абсолютно всё равно, останется этот вопрос закрытым или открытым.
- Убрать минусы. Эм.. Во-первых, это в принципе невозможно. Во-вторых, люди высказали своё мнение - с какой стати кто-то должен заявить, что его мнение важнее мнения 9 человек? Ну и наконец, этот вопрос получил +3 -9, т. е. суммарное изменение твоего рейтинга за этот вопрос +8 и ещё +2 за принятие ответа - итого +10.

> хочу его удалить

Итак, ты хочешь удалить вопрос вместе с ответом другого человека.
При этом у вас обоих уменьшится рейтинг.
А у тебя ещё и ухудшится статистика по закрытым и удалённым вопросам.
**Ну а где польза-то??**

Comment: `Не впечатляет, есть куча кода, в которой лень разбираться. Но кто-то разобрался и ответил.` - кстати, куча минусов и закрытие и, собсн, комментарии под вопросом были оттого, что никакого кода в вопросе не было. Там и вопроса даже не было.. там ни одного знака вопроса не было. Только *ссылка на видео с реализацией* О_________О ........ А отвечающий кажется написал там что-то с нуля >_<  ..... а потом только ТС что-то добавил, но кто-то, видимо за компанию, уже жахнул последний голос за закрытие

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ну ладно, давай переоткроем, раз уж автор постарался и улучшил вопрос. А то я что-то в историю не заглянул)))

Comment: Я обновил то сообщение и задал там свой вопрос. @Алексей Шиманский спасибо за ваш комментарий, он очень красочный. Как тогда написал, повторю и сейчас, это было мое первое сообщение на данном ресурсе, думаю в таком случае, "бывалым" пользователям стоит быть более снисходительным к ошибкам. Можно моей позиции придерживаться, а можно вашей, от выбора, и комментарии соответствующие.

Comment: @Qwertiy Благодарю за ваш ответ!  `Ну а где польза-то??` дело конечно не в рейтинге, а в логике, считаю,что я мысль свою донес в полной мере. Предполагаю, что `мета` это то место, где рядовой пользователь может что-то спросить/узнать(как сделал я) и здесь отвечают модераторы. "Модератор прислушается к голосу логики и откроет/удалит вопрос" - так я предполагал. Понравилась тема, на которую вы дали ссылку, там даже комментарий захотелось оставить.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov `"бывалым" пользователям стоит быть более снисходительным к ошибкам.` - или новичкам, скорее, нужно, для начала, ознакамливаться с правилами ресурса, которые чуть ли не принудительно показывают на этапе регистрации, а не бежать сломя голову, спотыкаясь и падая, уверенным в собственной правоте и важности своих действий, а потом грустить об этом и думать, что их тут не понимают..

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Купив пистолет вы наверняка прочитаете как пользоваться, что куда вставлять, где предохранитель, а не начнете стрелять, сделав в себе дырки, а потом говорить производителю, что вы новичок и надо было предупредить, что он стреляет.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Я понял вашу позицию, остается надеяться, что вы также критично и строго подходите к собственным ошибкам. Повторю, то сообщение я обновил и вопрос там задал, нужен еще один голос для открытия вопроса. Кстати, как сообщение обновил, еще минус за него добавился ) кто-то видимо думает зря ... логика где ты.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, когда появились голоса на переоткрытие, вопрос отправился в очередь проверок и привлёк дополнительное внимание. А лишняя правка ещё и подняла его на главную страницу.

Comment: @Qwertiy Его открыли, но в топ на главную он не поднимается, я еще отредактировал сообщение(улучшил описание), но на главной его нет, и по метке `javascript` его также нет наверху. Проверил по поиску, находится.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, ну сейчас-то нет. Вообще, обычно вопросы после правок попадают на главную, хотя я подумал... Возможно, к сильно заминусованным это не относится. Надо тогда на другой вкладке смотреть.

Comment: @Qwertiy по метке `javascript` я посмотрел 10 вкладок, его там нет. Видимо он где был, там и остался. Нужно как-то его поднять(я бы обратился к модератору, но предполагаю, что это бесполезно), иначе вероятность ответа на вопрос невысокая, а следовательно все эти правки не имеют смысла. @Qwertiy попробуйте вы внести правку, возможно поднимет.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, а зачем его поднимать? Там же уже есть принятый ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy Отвечу вам и на это. Как видно я без проблем открыл конкурс [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/617230/234502), при этом мне не пришлось снимать галку принятого ответа, следовательно, сама система не запрещает при принятом ответе искать более лучшие. Более того, на ваш этот вопрос, уже есть ответ, он появляется при открытии конкурса(один из вариантов), а именно` "Имеющиеся ответы устарели, необходимо проверить их с учётом недавних изменений."` Как известно из данной темы, я был вынужден изменить свой вопрос,при этом сохранив оригинал, т.к. на него был дан корректный ответ.