# Вопросы–домашние задания

Tags: поддержка

Пожалуйста, помните, что вопрос делает плохим не то, что он является домашним заданием, а то, что он не содержит конкретной прикладной проблемы в формулировке или надуман и не имеет никакой практической пользы ([более развернуто](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/6)). Подозрения, что вопрос является «домашним заданием», само по себе не является причиной для его закрытия или удаления.

Из справочного центра

> …
>
> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:
>
> - **к конкретной задаче программирования**: коду, алгоритмам, реализации алгоритмов на определенных языках программирования;
>
> …
>
> - **к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике**, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального администрирования IT систем.

<sub>Выделение добавлено мной.</sub>

Как можно видеть, по определению, любые вопросы, не содержащие конкретной прикладной проблемы, недопустимы на сайте. Большинство перепечатанных домашних заданий, за некоторым исключением, можно отнести к данной категории нетематических вопросов. Исключения:

1. *Вопросы академической направленности, которые можно преобразовать в вопросы соревнования*. Некоторые преподаватели подходят нестандартно к формированию задач учащимся – их задачи крайне интересны, необычны и представляют собой отличную разминку для ума! Если задание в вопросе интересное, отредактируйте его так, чтобы вопрос соответствовал критериям метки [соревнование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).
2. *Вопросы, которые можно преобразовать в энциклопедические*. Самые простые вопросы по прошествии лет и получении опыта могут быть рассмотрены с совершенно новых точек зрения. Если вы видите вопрос «явно из университетского курса», на который у вас есть увлекательный ответ, раскрывающий тему с неожиданной точки зрения, отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы он соответствовал критериям сайта, и опубликуйте ваш ответ!

Если вы видите вопрос, *который не соответствует правилам сайта*, в том числе вопрос–домашнее задание, который невозможно свести к исключениям, пожалуйста, проголосуйте «против» и за закрытие вопроса. Подобные сообщения следует закрывать как вопросы «не содержащие вопроса». Это новая причина закрытия, которая была добавлена по результатам предыдущих многочисленных обсуждений ([в частности ответа @VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5003/6))

> «Не по теме»
>
> Сообщение содержит лишь текст задачи, в котором нет описания проблемы, либо вопрос чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»). Для повторного открытия вопроса, добавьте описание конкретной проблемы, поясните, что именно не получается, в чём вы видите проблему.

(Если вы считаете, что формулировку причины закрытия можно улучшить, пожалуйста, оставьте ваш отзыв в ответе к этому вопросу.)

**Вопросы–домашние задания != вопросы, где подразумевается работа за автора**

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что далеко не каждый вопрос, в котором автор просит у сообщества помощи, является домашним заданием. Более того, в общем случае, *[вопросы, в которых подразумевается предоставление реализации, приветствуются](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4882/)*.

*Проголосуйте «против» и за закрытие, укажите конкретные проблемы вопроса в комментариях и остановитесь на этом.* Пожалуйста, не добавляйте [никому ненужный шум](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2349/) в систему. Вместе мы собираем базу прикладных решений русскоязычного сообщества, в которой нет места не только надуманным задачам, но и агрессии!

Comment: у меня легкое дежавю

Comment: Полностью согласен что с этим надо что то решать. Вопросы в которых автор просит сделать что то за него сейчас просто наводнили SO. Их всех минусуют но с их репой эти минусы не сделают им никакой погоды. Единственное что им нужно это что бы кто то решил их задачу и решальщики находятся. Поэтому таких вопросов будет всё больше и больше и уже найти интересные вопросы становиться сложнее и сложнее, а это значит что авторы хороших вопросов могут получить менее качественный ответ или не получить его вовсе.

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов Не все вопросы–домашние задания плохие! Мы будем бороться только с теме, что не соответствуют нашему представлению о сайте. Увеличение количества интересных вопросов – отдельная проблема, которую необходимо решать независимо от уменьшения плохих!

Comment: @Grundy  Пожалуйста, поясните, что именно вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, мне кажется уже несколько раз обсуждали эту тему, не очень понимаю чем данный вопрос отличается от всех предыдущих

Comment: @Grundy Эта публикация – результат обсуждений. Можно рассматривать ее как официальную позицию по вопросам–домашним заданиям и ссылаться на этот вопрос, если у кого–то появится разногласия.

Comment: предсказание: вопросы, которые не демонстрируют достаточно усилий вне зависимости полезны они  или нет будут закрываться как *"вопросы «не содержащие вопроса»"* (отличие от текущей ситуации, что [липовые причины](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4868/23044) участникам, которым наплевать на полезность вопросов, не придётся использовать). Иначе говоря: этой причиной будут злоупотреблять как и всеми предыдущими её аналогами такими как "minimal understanding" (не конец света, но жаль что миссия сайта и предыдущий опыт игнорируются).

Comment: @jfs Данная причина закрытия – это попытка разделить вопросы, предполагающие работу за автора и сообщения похожие на домашние задания, которые не содержат вопроса вовсе. Если попытка неудачная, сделаем новую. Будем пробовать пока не найдем то, что нам подходит. Если у вас есть конкретные замечания, пожалуйста, опубликуйте их в ответе.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky [свой ответ и моё отношение к этой проблеме я уже опубликовал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044). И я не вижу отличия (мы находимся в области казуистики, когда "истина" и "правда" отличаются как-то -- технически может вы и можете определения для себя создать, что "работа за автора" и "вопросы-домашние задания" это разные тематики, но на практике нереально это определение донести до людей, которые закрывают вопросы -- с практической точки зрения слишком тесно переплетены эти тематики).

Comment: Ещё раз: *"Closing is a perfectly good tool for off-topic questions, a reasonable tool for unclear or subjective questions, and even a decent enough tool for duplicates. But **it simply doesn't work for these, and after years of trying to make it work it's time we admitted that.**"*

Comment: @jfs: А вот если будет, то тогда мы и будем работать над этим. Пока проблемы нет, давайте не будем её решать.

Comment: @VladD: проблема уже есть, ей много лет (попробуйте пару ссылок, которые я привёл почитать).

Comment: @jfs: Я согласен с тем, что закрывать потому что гуглится — неправильно. Я также согласен с тем, что закрывать вопросы без кода — неправильно. Но я не согласен с тем, что закрывать домашки неправильно. Я разделяю мнение Николаса, выраженное в этом вопросе: домашка обычно — плохой вопрос, и может быть хорошим лишь в случаях, если (1) это интересное гольфообразное упражнение, (2) это вопрос из серии «FAQ для новичков». Большинство вопросов-домашних заданий в реальности _ужасны_.

Comment: @jfs: Таким образом, я думаю, что проблема, о которой вы говорите, существует, но конкретно в данном случае у нас противоположная проблема: для очевидно нуждающегося в закрытии вопроса нет подходящей причины, и приходится «натягивать» существующие причины.

Comment: @VladD если почитать историю этого вопроса, то можно узнать  что уже неоднократно вводились причины закрытия (типа "not a real question", "minimal understanding"), призванные бороться с homework-вопросами. Как ясно из моих слов и приведённой цитаты выше (даже не читая ссылок — хотя я рекомендую [целиком ответ прочитать, из которого цитата взята](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308842/4279)), *практика показала что это не работает*: полезные вопросы закрываются, а мусор это  заметно не останавливает.

Comment: @VladD я не достаточно знаю о динамике роста сообществ типа SO, чтобы понять насколько вредно это сейчас (может наоборот полезно на какое-то время ужесточить политику). Наиболее [вероятный сценарий я выше указал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5043/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f#comment18459_5043)

Comment: @jfs: В таком случае я предлагаю нам (то есть, мне и вам, и другим небезразличным участникам) понаблюдать за тем, не скатываемся ли мы массово в ваш сценарий _на вопросах с домашними заданиями_, и если да, поднимать вопрос снова. На то и Мета, чтобы эволюционно развивать политику сайта.

Comment: @VladD: совершенно согласен, вопрос в том как измерять (если заранее критерии не установить, то задним числом человек способен всё что угодно рационализировать). Заметят ли изменение люди, которые не закрывают вопросы -- повлияет ли на репутацию SO. Повлияет ли это на то кто задаёт и какие вопросы. Как часто люди, которые хотят ответить на вопрос, будут натыкаться на закрытие (как на участие влияет).  Увеличит/уменьшит грубость в комментариях, направленную на авторов вопросов. Как изменятся [метрики важные для качества информации на сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044), итд.

Comment: @jfs: Ну, пока объективных критериев нет, придётся доверять своим субъективным, ну и допускать возможность ошибки. Мне кажется это разумным черновым вариантом, если нету других. Ну и можно создать (точнее, воссоздать) «чат открывашек», в котором сообщать случаи незаслуженно (по субъективному мнению участника) закрытых вопросов и обсуждать то, а действительно ли вопрос незаслуженно закрыт, и если заслуженно, то как можно (и можно ли вообще) его исправить/спасти.

Comment: @jfs: Если такие случаи будут регулярно обсуждаться, то будет видно, (1) увеличивается или уменьшается поток неправильно закрытых вопросов, (2) кто из участников слишком строг к новичкам. Это, конечно, «ручное управление» сайтом, но пока наш размер сильно не дотягивает до en.SO, это может быть эффективным.

Comment: @VladD явные вещи (known unknowns), которые на ходу можно починить не вызывают вопросов (сломалось, починили — часто ломается, попробовали что-то ещё). Для относительно небольшого сайта, вызывает вопрос наличие скрытых нелинейных последствий (unknown unknowns), которые рост сайта могут убить. Точку невозврата можно пройти не зная об этом (облучился 8 Gy и готово). Наличие разных мнений необходимо для здоровья сообщества, но то что некоторые активные участники миссию сайта не разделяют/по разному видят, может к перерождению привести. К примеру, если сарказм не полоть, то он заразен и способен..

Comment: ...необратимо сигнал/шум ухудшить (остаются только люди, которые его могут переносить, что усиливает порочный круг). С другой стороны, инерция от других факторов (к примеру, наличия английского SO и его культуры) может быть настолько большая, что курс сайта заметно ничто не изменит.