# Нужно ли приводить MCVE в случае публикации вопроса с самоответом?

Tags: обсуждение, самоответы, mcve

Как известно, некоторые вопросы предлагается закрывать по причине отсутствия в них [минимального, самодостаточного, воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

> [image: не по теме]

Причина вполне разумна. Но что делать, если участник хочет поделиться решением своей проблемы, опубликовав одновременно вопрос-ответ без приведения MCVE? Например, проблема может быть описана словесно, приведены какие-то скриншоты и т.п., может быть даже часть кода, но явно без соответствия MCVE, т.к. само создание MCVE может быть довольно утомительным.

Допустимо ли публиковать подобные вопросы? Мне кажется, в них есть смысл.

---

Приведу конкретный пример из практики, собственно, побудивший к заданию этого вопроса.

В GUI приложении возникла проблема, что выделение текста внутри метки (label), помещённого в табличное представление приводило к дёрганью строки вверх-вниз. Решение проблемы нашлось в небольшом увеличении вертикальных полей метки так, чтобы появление выделения части текста не приводило к дёрганью. Для публикации подобного решения (и создания полноценного вопроса), как мне кажется, понадобилось бы описать как создаётся эта метка, куда добавляется и т.д. и т.п. (то есть предоставить тот самый MCVE). Однако, концептуально, вопрос-ответ, описывающий проблему дёрганья мог быть полезен и без MCVE другим участникам, просто людям пришедшим из гугла и даже завтрашнему мне.

Надеюсь, подобный пример лучше прояснит суть обозначенного мета-вопроса.

Так как некоторые не видят различия между текущим вопросом и другим ([Следует ли закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3851)), поясняю:

> Суть текущего вопроса в выяснении наличия или отсутствии преференции у вопроса с само ответом. В предложенном дубликате об этом и речи нет.

Comment: Во-первых, самоответность к делу не относится. Во-вторых, уточните, пожалуйста, вы про то что **MCVE вопросу нужен, но его составлять утомительно**, или про то что вам кажется, что даже если **MCVE вопросу не нужен, ruSO все равно заставляет его сделать**?

Comment: *"самоответность к делу не относится"* Вообще-то в этом вся суть вопроса, так что оно не может не относиться к делу. Нужен ли MCVE это тоже часть вопроса. Например, я предполагаю, что MCVE может быть выражен текстом (алгоритмически), а не кодом, но вроде как не все согласны тут с таким подходом.

Comment: Так и какие же преференции по вашему самоответность должна тут давать? И вы не ответили на второй вопрос.

Comment: @Kromster я, надеюсь, дал ответ на хотя бы один из Ваших вопросов из комментария в правке к сообщению. Речь как раз о наличии или отсутствии преференции у вопроса с само ответом. Поэтому странно утверждать (в комментарии, а не отдельном ответе), что к делу это не относится. Вот в ответе это будет уместно смотреться.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Следует ли закрывать все вопросы, в которых нет кода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3851/%d0%a1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Comment: О ... @Grundy проснулся :) Здесь акцент на особенности самоответов, а не большинства рядовых вопросов.

Comment: @älёxölüt, какая связь? Есть вопрос - в вопросе не обязателен [mcve] . Не важно кто именно напишет ответ

Comment: @Grundy ох ... ё. Почитайте [коммент](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8508/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-mcve-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc?noredirect=1#comment35202_8508) выше. Я уже объяснял это.

Comment: @älёxölüt, все еще не вижу отличий текущего вопроса от вопроса указанного в дубликате.

Comment: @Grundy тогда повторяю: суть текущего вопроса в выяснении наличия или отсутствии преференции у вопроса с само ответом. В предложенном дубликате об этом и речи нет.

Comment: @älёxölüt, об этом нет, потому что вопрос с самоответом ничем не отличается от вопроса без самоответа.

Comment: @Grundy ну, тогда попробуйте дать ответ на чужой вопрос, чтобы у них время публикации совпало.

Comment: @älёxölüt, время публикации ни на что не влияет, плюс можно попросить сотрудника поменять дату публикации ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Вопрос с самоответом ничем не отличается от любого другого, а значит, и требования насчет MCVE такие же. Более того, обычно для уже решенной проблемы MCVE найти куда проще чем для нерешенной...

Однако, обращаю внимание на то, что в общем случае код в вопросе вовсе не обязателен! Код обязателен только в том случае, когда в вопросе требуется помочь с отладкой, поскольку это невозможно сделать не видя кода.

Comment: Получается, словесное описание всё же может являться MCVE и без непосредственно кода?

Comment: Можно даже больше сказать - далеко не все хорошие вопросы должны быть в формате MCVE ;-)

Comment: @älёxölüt нет. Словесного описания может быть достаточно даже без MCVE.

Comment: Не очень понимаю тогда. Если нет MCVE, то вопрос можно закрыт по причине его отсутствия. С другой стороны, Вы говорите, что словесного описания может быть достаточно, и тогда закрывать вопрос не стоит. Я в затруднении.

Comment: @älёxölüt покажите место в правилах, где написано все все вопросы без MCVE должны быть закрыты.

Comment: @älёxölüt попробуйте пройтись по https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes и посчитать, какая часть находящихся на первой странице вопросов содержит MCVE...

Comment: Тогда покажите мне место, где я говорил про "все вопросы". В [тексте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8508/176217) я указал, что *"некоторые вопросы предлагается закрывать"*, а не все.

Comment: Ну так и я говорил про то, что *некоторые* вопросы не стоит закрывать. Вы написали что теперь находитесь в затруднении, из чего я и заключил что вы  собирались ранее закрыть все вопросы без MCVE.

Comment: Добавил пример в вопросе.

Answer (score 3):

> **некоторые** вопросы предлагается закрывать по причине отсутствия в них MCVE. ... **создание MCVE может быть довольно утомительным.**

То есть речь о ***некоторых*** вопросах, а не обо всех, а конкретнее о тех, которым MCVE все же нужен?

У меня для вас хорошие новости - далеко не всем вопросам нужен MCVE!

---

### В таком случае, да, нужно.

Вопрос с самоответом ничем принципиально не отличается от других вопросов и ответов и не имеет каких-либо преференций.

Если у вас нет MCVE, то как вы докажете, что решение действительно решает озвученную проблему? А то у меня тут *"давеча машина не заводилась, я постучал по колесу и это решило проблему"* или *"выделение и освобождение 10мб памяти при старте приложения надежно и воспроизводимо позволяет избежать Access Violation при работе"*.

MCVE так же побуждает к отсечению всего лишнего и приближению к сути проблемы. То есть уходу от эникейства и приближению к пониманию.

Comment: Ваш пример не очень подходит под ситуацию, так как не позволяет больше повторить проблему. Я же говорю о ситуациях, когда изменение кода проблему решает, а если изменения откатить - проблема снова имеет место быть.

Comment: Пример с куском памяти более реалистичен, но Вы же, надеюсь, понимаете, что подобный ответ явно будет заминусован, так как не решает проблему, а лишь завуалирует её, хотя [некоторым подходит и такое](https://twitter.com/pomeranian99/status/858856994438094848). Я же имею в виду несколько более правдоподобные с точки зрения устранения причины, а не симптомов решения. И, кстати, уточните, пожалуйста, ситуацию о допустимости подобных вопросов. Если такая публикация не является по Вашему мнению допустимой, то она, как я считаю, должна быть удалена. Правильный ли я вывод сделал из Вашего сообщения?

Comment: Я бы хотел дать более точный ответ, но сам вопрос слишком расплывчат. Сейчас он читается как "у меня есть решение для некоторой проблемы в коде, но мне лень приводить код к виду MCVE".

Comment: Замените "лень" на "требует существенного времени" и это действительно то, о чём вопрос. Тут всё верно.

Comment: [mcve] должен быть в ответе, а не в вопросе.

Comment: Да вы что? ) По-хорошему, MCVE должен быть в вопросе (т.к. само требование приведения вопроса к виду MCVE в 75% случаев решает проблему) и реже, в ответе (в меньшей степени, т.к. зачастую ответ указывает на исправление и не ставит собой целью продублировать вопрос.).

Comment: @Kromster само приведение вопроса к виду MCVE не решает проблему, а лишь упрощает поиск решения. Но если проблема уже решена (самоответ), то приведение вопроса к MCVE именно для упрощения поиска решения бессмысленно. Конечно, может быть ситуация, что решение фактически лишь завуалирует проблему, но это отдельная ситуация, имхо.

Comment: @Kromster Вот пример вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937884/unity-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bf%d0%b0-swipe/937885#937885  Как по мне, то он не требует MCVE. Обьясни мне на вот этом конкретном примере почему здесь MCVE нужен. Лично ты должен знать аргументацию почему, т.к. ты по какой-то причине проголосовал за закрытие.

Comment: @Andrew еще раз акцентирую внимание - **"далеко не всем вопросам нужен MCVE!"**. Теперь второе, касательно лично моего голоса за закрытие вашего вопроса (за других не могу утверждать), - вопрос выглядит черезчур кратким, его стоит расширить и дополнить (например, обозначить почему не работает решение предлагаемое в Юнити "из коробки", кратко описать типовые неработающие подходы, обозначить область применения (пк, таблет, смартфон, VR)), как вы сделали с предыдущим вопросом.

Comment: `вопрос выглядит черезчур кратким` -- и что? Если он самодостаточен, то какая разница. Мне его делать длиннее чисто что бы сделать длиннее? ; `например, кратко описать типовые неработающие подходы` 1. для чего? 2. для чего это делать в вопросе? ; `обозначить облать применения` в даном случае тот кто знает слово "свайп" и гуглит по ключевым словам "свайп" и "юнити" ТОЧНО прям на 100% знает области применения. Да и код будет работать на любых девайсах с тачскрином. Собственно, сам свайп это фишка тачскринов... Было бы странно гуглить свайп для девайсов без тачскрина.

Comment: @Andrew вы попросили пояснение, вы его получили. Мне вопрос самодостаточным не показался. Причины и предложения я указал. Если вас интересует дальнейшее обсуждение - давайте вести в том вопросе или в чате.

Answer (score 3):

## Нет, не нужно

Какой смысл загромождать канонический вопрос каким-то левым нерабочим кодом, если сразу сам же публикуешь рабочий код в ответе? И где вообще этот нерабочий код взять?

Т. е. код где-то должен быть, но гораздо правильнее опубликовать сразу только правильно работающий [mcve] в ответе.

Вот, например, [вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432369/178988) - какой код предлагается в него поместить?

Comment: Откуда вы взяли "каноничность" вопроса? И почему надо именно *загромождать левым нерабочим кодом*? P.S. Жирноту лишнюю уберете, или нам тоже пожирнить свои заголовки? )

Comment: @Kromster, ну 1. вопросы с самоответом - как правило канонические. 2. А как ещё это назвать, если не заграмождением? Если код работает, то ему место в ответе, а не в вопросе. Получается, в вопрос надо поместить код, который не работает. Зачем это делать и где его взять? 3. По поводу жирности - да, я бы выделил во всех ответах. Вроде так принято в голосованиях? 4. Добавил пример в ответ.

Comment: 1. Отнюдь. 2. Загромождение называть загромождением, а MCVE по делу - называть MCVE. Уже писал в комментариях, **далеко не всем вопросам нужен код и MCVE, но ТС ставит вопрос так, что ему лень писать MCVE, который по его мнению все же нужен**. 3. Ок. 4. Хороший пример, см. п.2

Comment: Добавил пример в вопрос.

Comment: @älёxölüt, посмотрел, считаю, что там можно и без примера обойтись.

Answer (score 2):

Да, нужно.

Я над таким вопросом думал вчера, когда закрывал [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/929888/213987) вопрос. (И [вот ещё например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/931979/213987))

У участника была проблема, код он приложить не захотел. Такие вопросы нужно закрывать, потому что у нас технический ресурс, а не соревнование телепатов, которые умеют толковать сны и описания кода словами. Множество таких вопросов просто забрасываются.

Поэтому даже с учётом того, что автор решил свою проблему к моменту, когда я делал проверку вопроса и опубликовал ответ я всё равно решил, что вопрос должен быть закрыт.

Я не могу уверенно сказать, какую проблему автор решил. Этот вопрос даже будучи закрытым доступен в поиске, он никуда не делся. Этот вопрос и ответ автору оказался полезен - хорошо, вот ответ, никуда не делся. Полезен ли он посетителям? Нет, так как нет подробного описания что за проблема была: если появится похожий вопрос - то лучше всего писать новый топик, возможно указывать ссылку на старый но никак не отвечать в непонятно как сформулированный вопрос.

Если же автор изначально имел решение и сразу оформлял вопрос самоответом, то тем более он должен чётко сформулировать проблему: ему и так уже всё понятно, поэтому нужно думать о удобстве пользователей базы знаний.

Поэтому:

> Нужно ли приводить MCVE

Да, нужно.

> т.к. само создание MCVE может быть довольно утомительным.

Хм. Очень странный аргумент.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что вопрос заслуживает закрытия, но ни в коем случае не удаления?

Comment: @älёxölüt Абсолютно правильно: закрытия и последующей доработки, но не удаления.

Comment: Добавил пример в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

MCVE в виде кода нужен в вопросах "почему не работает код". Если суть вопроса - проблема в проектировании макета GUI, и применяемый фреймворк не позволяет компактно отразить макет GUI в виде кода, то да, целесообразнее приводить MCVE в другом виде. Использовать только скриншоты, скорее всего, плохая идея, а вот словесное описание, в какой конфигурации нужно добавить элементы на форму для воспроизведения проблемы, подходит. В причине закрытия текст рассчитан на наиболее популярный случай, но это не значит, что надо везде пихать именно код.

Answer (score -1):

## Нет, не нужно. Достаточно MC без VE.

Кто вообще делится "решениями" проблем?
Те, кто столкнулся с какой-то достаточно распространенной проблемой, но при этом не нашел решения на вопрос или же нашел, но с трудом. Он хочет поделиться решением проблемы. Описывает ее в той мере, в которой считает ее самодостаточной.

> то есть MC.

Ну вот, например, я знаю про очень распространенную проблему — "работа с OpenFileDialog/SaveFileDialog в Selenium". Селениум не умеет с ними работать вообще. В интернете одни костыли и то зачастую нерабочие или которые подходят под очень узкий круг ресурсов. Вот я могу решить проблему и поделиться с общественностью.

Объясните мне, для чего мне расписывать вопрос, если я делюсь этим универсальным решением? Я знаю про проблему. Я кратко и четко описал проблему заголовком `работа с OpenFileDialog/SaveFileDialog в Selenium` и, допустим, описанием "в интернете, к сожалению, универсального решения не нашлось, поэтому делюсь с общественностью". Все метки будут проставлены правильно: "SeleniumWebDriver" "OpenFileDialog" "SaveFileDialog".

Это самодостаточный вопрос. **ОН УЖЕ Minimal, Complete и он НЕ ТРЕБУЕТ Verifiable Example**

И сразу же ответ, который бы это решил.

И я даю гарантию, что его закроют, несмотря на то что он MC.

> Я, например, собирался запостить как-то решение на эту проблему, которая существует уже c 2004 года и не имеет элегантного решения в интернете **вообще** за все эти годы.

Объясните мне, для чего здесь MCVE?

Или конкретно уже созданный вопрос: 
[Unity реализация свайпа / Swipe](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937884)

Уже заголовок описывает конкретную проблему: отловка свайпов в юнити.

Какое еще MCVE, если вопрос описывает в достаточной мере конкретную проблему? Для чего здесь VE?

Для чего мне постить чей-то нерабочий код, а потом же постить рабочий себе в ответ? Это по меньшей мере глупо и бесполезно.

## Закрытие подобных вопросов отбивает желание делиться решениями. Это вредит сообществу.

Comment: 1. Вы упорно путаете теплое с мягким и объединяете их в одно, тогда как это два разных множества. ***Не всем вопросам нужен MCVE.*** 2. Касательно вашего тезиса *"для чего мне расписывать вопрос если я делюсь этим универсальным решением"* - на SO есть принятый формат "вопрос/ответ" и не важно, как и кем они были размещены, требования к ним едины. Делиться решениями без обозначения проблем - лучше в личном блоге ;-)

Comment: Касательно вашего вопроса - *"Unity реализация свайпа / Swipe. Во многих играх нужно отлавливание жестов, в т.ч. жест свайпа."* Вы правда считаете это (полный текст) достаточным описанием? Даже тут, вы проливаете больше света на тему - "проблему: отловка свайпов в юнити.", то есть в Юнити с этим есть какая-то проблема, подводные камни?

Comment: @Kromster То есть с этим достаточно людей сталкиваются и при этом в интернете много стремных решений. Часть из которых сейчас на юнити даже не запустится ибо современный юнити не поддерживает JS. :) Да, я правда считаю что вопрос "работа со свайпами в Unity" является самодостаточным.

Comment: Было бы здорово их как-то включить в вопрос (кратко, на словах) - это увеличит "искабельность" вашего вопроса - т.е. вопрос получит внимание тех кто ищет "делаю свайп в Юнити через АБС" (больше ключевых понятий в тексте). И хорошо бы обозначить, чем же все-таки штатный свайп не подходит. Раз уж вопрос претендует на FAQ. *тогда с радостью флагну на переоткрытие и +1*

Comment: @Kromster а в юнити есть штатный свайп? На сколько я знаю его там нет и не было никогда.

Comment: Без понятия - вот вам и первое предложение *"К сожалению, в Юнити версии такой-то до сих пор нету штатной поддержки свайпа"*

Comment: А как это улучшит вопрос? Ну то есть... Это улучшит его читабельность? Это улучшит его искабельность? Что конкретно добавление этого текста улучшит? Вот серьезно, я не вижу смысла это добавлять.

Comment: Проблема не в том, что у вас нет MCVE, а в том, что у вас нет вопроса. Нормальный вопрос на эту тему должен выглядеть как-то так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540109/Двигать-спрайт-свайпами-по-экрану?rq=1

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight только вот в приведенном примере свайпы вообще не при чем...  Там нужна блокировка по оси Y и драг обьекта. То есть в пример ты мне ставишь вообще неправильно заданный вопрос который к свайпам даже отношения не имеет на практике. Шикарно.

Comment: @Andrew это улучшит его искабельность и читабельность. Скажу за себя, если я буду гуглить этот вопрос, то вероятно буду использовать другие термины (и вопрос по ним не найдется), и даже найдя и открыв вопрос, я увижу, что он по сути туториал, и не ясно, насколько мне придется перелопачивать весь свой код, чтобы его внедрить (т.е. даже неясно, этот способ претендует на каноничность или это локальный велосипед).

Comment: Можно поинтересоватся, какие например термины ты бы гуглил? Ну просто я серьезно не представляю как можно гуглить это окроме "swipe unity". Т.к. абсолютно не важно что конкртено будет подписано на свайп в любого из пользователей. Это как гуглить по-другому "Form OnClose"... Просто не представляю и все.

Comment: @Andrew чтобы не ходить далеко за примерами, по названию ваш вопрос уже в топе гугла, а вот по "свайп на юнити" его и в 10 нет. На этом участие в дискуссии заканчиваю. Позиция вам, надеюсь более чем ясна, а спорить ради спора - незачем.

Comment: @Andrew только вот этот "неправильно заданный вопрос" не закрыт, а ваш "правильно заданный" - закрыт. Странно, не правда ли? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/864380/Считывать-свайпы-пальцем-по-экрану-unity-c?rq=1 - тоже неправильный?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Не играл в "Clash Of Clans", так что я не знаю. Но личто я бы этот вопрос закрыл как не отвечающий MCVE. Автор не удосужился навести пример того что имеет ввиду и просит, фактически, гуглить видео, на которых [вангую!], люди, скорее всего, не увидят вот тех свайпов, про которых автор говорит.  А сейчас настало время проверить мое вангование. Через минутку отпишусь.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight блииин, внезапно, мое вангование сработало. Гуглил по "Clash Of Clans gameplay". Я не понимаю по видосиках что автор имеет ввиду. И, наверное, именно потому он и остался без ответа. Это что, серьезно пример хорошо заданного вопроса о свайпах? Третий пример правильного вопроса будет?

Comment: @Kromster `чтобы не ходить далеко за примерами, по названию ваш вопрос уже в топе гугла, а вот по "свайп на юнити" его и в 10 нет` а так почти всегда. Неужели, ты думаешь что по всем ключевикам свежезаданный вопрос сразу поднимается в топ гугла? Это случается только в том случае если ключевики низкоранжируемые. А я не знал что "свайп" и "юнити" это редкие ключевики.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight так что, ты можешь мне оьяснить, чем конкретно мой `MC` вопрос со свайпом и правильным ответом хуже чем 1. вопрос который вообще решается по-другому (т.е. автор через неопытность решил что делается через свайпы хотя это не так) и ответ возможно будет найти только по совсем "левым" ключевикам 2. вопрос у которого отсутствуют все составляющие `MCVE` и на который вообще не ответили? Вот я на полном серьезе не понимаю. Обьясни, пожалуста. Ты же эти линки скинул как примеры.

Comment: @Andrew я уже написал - в нем нет вопроса. Проблема только в этом, все остальное: MCVE, опытность автора, ключевые слова, правильность ответа и прочее, не имеют никакого значения.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight на этот раз я тебя понял и услышал. Спасибо.